# Bing Maps AJAX v7.0 Control Not Working Since this Morning

Tags: bing-maps

I've been working with the Bing Maps AJAX v7 control for a few months now.
I ran my app this morning and none of the maps appeared - just blank
pages - my code has not changed. I even tested an old version I had deployed elsewhere which is been working for months - it's now also broken.

Digging deeper and playing with the styling, I got the control to
render, and it said that my key was invalid.

Doing the same playing around with the styling on the next page made
the control appear (wrong dimensions), but no warning about the
invalid credentials.

I have tried creating a new Developer key and using that but I get the
same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the Microsoft.Maps.Map object before calling other objects such as Pushpin, Location etc. I ran into the same problem and changing the order fixed the issue.